# Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^+ $. If $b\mid a$ and $b\mid (a+2)$ , prove that $b=1$ or $b=2$

Tags: integers

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^+ $. If $b\mid a$ and $b\mid (a+2)$ , prove that $b=1$ or $b=2$. Now, we have $a = b\,n$ and $a+2 = b\,m$ for some $m$ and $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose that $b \ne 1$. So, we have $2 = (m-n) b$. This means that $b\mid 2$. Since $b \in \mathbb{Z}^+ $ and  $b \ne 1$, we have $b \geqslant 2$. So, $b \geqslant (m-n) b$. Since $b > 0$, we get $(m-n) \leqslant 1$. Now, since $2 = (m-n) b$, we have $(m-n) > 0 $ and since $(m-n) \in \mathbb{Z}$, we get $ (m-n) \geqslant 1$. Together with $ (m-n) \leqslant 1$, this means that $(m-n) = 1$. So, we have $b = 2$.

Is this a good proof ?

Thanks

Comment: Correct, but quite complicated. Once you have $b|2$, it is immediate that the only possibilities are $1$ and $2$.

Comment: @thesilverdoe It was not apparent to me. What theorem would we use from that point on ?

Comment: You could just write $2=bc$ for an integer $c$, so $b = 2/c$ and because $c \geq 1$, you get $b \leq 2$. Generally, if $p|q$ then you must have $p\leq q$...

Comment: @user9026, May I ask why is $\ b|2$ not sufficient to say that $\ b=1,2$? You have **unecessarily** written a long proof. And for your main question, it is **not** a **good** proof.

Comment: Vishnu, in proofs, we justify using known theorems. So, I wanted to as precise as possible

Comment: It would be foolish to justify that if $\ b|2$ and it is a positive integer, then $\ b=1, 2$ using **known theorems** instead of **known facts**.

Comment: @vishnu-kadiri Yes I get it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the start up to $ b \mid 2$.

The following steps can be simplified. Either:

- An integer $m$ that divides another one $n$ is smaller or equal to $n$. Therefore $b \in \{1,2\}$.
- Or the only natural integers that divide $2$ are $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is fine but it's a bit complicated. It can be done in a more easy way.

Just use the fact that if $b|a$ and $b|c$, then $b|(a - c). $The same thing goes here.

$b|(a + 2)$ and $b|a$ implies :-

$\rightarrow b|(a + 2) - a$

$\rightarrow b|2$

Since $a,b$ are positive integers the only possible choices for $b$ are $1,2$ .